# In R package 'timetk', how to understand the parameter 'difference' in function 'diff_vec'?

Tags: r, timetk

In R package 'timetk', how to understand the parameter 'difference' in function 'diff_vec'?

```
library(timetk)
1:10 %>% diff_vec(lag=1)
#result: [1] NA  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

I try to change the valus of 'difference', but can't understand the result

```
#what's the usage of parameter 'difference'

1:10 %>% diff_vec(lag=1,difference = 1)
#result: [1] NA  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
1:10 %>% diff_vec(lag=1,difference = 2)
#result: [1] NA NA  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
1:10 %>% diff_vec(lag=1,difference = 3)
#result: [1] NA NA NA  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easier to understand with `(1:10)^2`. Argument `difference` is perform difference(differential) between consecutive value multiple time.

```
(1:10)^2 %>% diff_vec(lag=1,difference = 1)
[1] NA  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19
```

For `difference = 2` means perform `difference = 1` twice.

```
(1:10)^2 %>% diff_vec(lag=1,difference = 1) %>% diff_vec(lag=1,difference = 1)
 [1] NA NA  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
(1:10)^2 %>% diff_vec(lag=1,difference = 2)
 [1] NA NA  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
```

In the same way, `difference = 3` means perform `difference = 1` three times.

```
(1:10)^2 %>% diff_vec(lag=1,difference = 1) %>% diff_vec(lag=1,difference = 1) %>% diff_vec(lag=1,difference = 1)
 [1] NA NA NA  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
(1:10)^2 %>% diff_vec(lag=1,difference = 3)
 [1] NA NA NA  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks for your sample , it's easier to understand